# UIWebView links inactive

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I have a webview that displays properly, however the links are entirely inactive. If I try to select a link the selection magnifying glass appears. I've tried overriding

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

but the method will not execute. The class extends `UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>`, and my view is located in a tabbar, but I'm fairly certain everything's connected properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property - Detects link in the UIWebView class to `YES`.